# How to center an offline map

Tags: here-api

We are using Here SDK for Flutter to download and save offline maps in our mobile app.

We would like to know how to center the map in the region center?

We have the region identifiers, and we would like to know how to get its center's coordinates.

Below the code we are using:

hereMapController.camera.lookAtPointWithMeasure(
GeoCoordinates(widget.step.location?.latitude ?? 0, widget.step.location?.longitude ?? 0),
MapMeasure(MapMeasureKind.distance, 70000),
);

We also tried "camera.state.targetCoordinates" but it didn't work.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mapview.getViewportSize and then get the centre coordinates from this Size2D object. After getting the centre coordinates you can use mapview.viewToGeoCoordinates​ to get the geo coordinates of the centre. then you can lookAt it.

Here you can find more -

1. getViewPortSize - https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.13.5.0/api_reference/com/here/sdk/mapview/MapView.html#getViewportSize()
2. viewToGeoCoordinates​ - https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.13.5.0/api_reference/com/here/sdk/mapview/MapView.html#viewToGeoCoordinates(com.here.sdk.core.Point2D)

I hope this will answer you query.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to center on a point, use this:

```
// Change zoom and location.
double distanceToEarthInMeters = 1000 * 2.0;
MapMeasure mapMeasureZoom = MapMeasure(MapMeasureKind.distance, distanceToEarthInMeters);
_hereMapController.camera.lookAtPointWithMeasure(GeoCoordinates(52.530932, 13.384915), mapMeasureZoom);
```

The camera [user guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/topics/camera.html#change-the-camera-location) lists more options.

If you know the encompassing bounding box of your `Region`. Then try this:

```
// Change location area and orientation.
var southWestCorner = GeoCoordinates(52.373556, 13.114358);
var northEastCorner = GeoCoordinates(52.611022, 13.479493);
var geoBox = GeoBox(southWestCorner, northEastCorner);
var bearing; // Set null, to keep bearing unchanged.
var tilt = 45.0;
var orientation = GeoOrientationUpdate(bearing, tilt);
_hereMapController.camera.lookAtAreaWithGeoOrientation(geoBox, orientation);
```

This will make sure the center of the passed box is shown.

There is also an overloaded method that accepts a list of points to be included in the area with an optional center (as look-at-target).

Comment: Thanks Nusatad, unfortunately this solution redirect always to these coordinates 52.53014738734338,13.386649060069317 (Berlin)